# How do I use a wildcard with arcpy.da.Walk

Tags: python, arcgis

I am trying to use a wildcard to pull out only certain types of relationship classes but don't know the syntax/usage of wildcards.

I have a piece of code that lists the relationship classes perfectly as I need it to.

```
ws = 'Database Connections\\gis@gisprod.sde'
arcpy.env.workspace = ws

featuredatasets = arcpy.ListDatasets("GIS.Wa*", "Feature")
fcs = []

print (featuredatasets)

# go into each feature dataset and get a list of relationship classes
for fd in featuredatasets:
    oldws = arcpy.env.workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = ws + "\\" + fd

    relationship_classes = next(arcpy.da.Walk(arcpy.env.workspace, datatype='RelationshipClass'))[2]
```

a listing of all relationship classes within the workspace that contain "Has" in their name

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about SQL Like Wildcard matching, then try using `fnmatch` module. It is a inbuilt module in Python which allows single character matching (via `?`) or global matching (via `*`).

Even though the main purpose of the module is for filename matching, but you can still use it for string pattern matching.

**Sample Code:**

```
import fnmatch

a = "hello"
print(fnmatch.fnmatch(a, "h*"))
```

**Output:**

```
True
```